# Qt QWebView, QWebengineview not working

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator, qt-designer

I'm new to Qt and I'd like to know how I can import the "qml" for QWebView and/or QWebengineview. I tried running the example but it gives me "unknown modules: qwebview" Same for Qwebengineview. In the QtDesigner, I don't see any of thoses. I need to include HTML in my project...
Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried including them in your pro file? like this?

```
QT += webengine webenginewidgets
```

Comment: If you are not sure it will work, you should put it as a comment